# Ontoggle change other li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a ul list, where one li elements has a thumbs up, and other haves a thumbs down, when i click each of the thumbs i add a class green or red depending of the type of thumb, but only one can be active or with color, if on of them is selected i need to remove the class of the other that is given a color (green, or red)

The problem is that i cant get the element to check if has the class or not.

My code:

```
 $('.approved').click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).toggleClass('bg-green');
    });

   $('.not-approved').click(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
 console.log($(this).parent().find('.approved').hasClass('bg-green'));
      $(this).toggleClass('bg-red');
    });
```

html:

```
<div class="options-tools pull-right">
                      <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up approved" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down not-approved" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                      </ul>
                </div>
```

Basically when i click on thumbs down (.not-approved), i add the color class 'bg-red', but before i need to chech if the "thumbs up" is active(bg-green).

What im doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to do `$('.approved').hasClass('bg-green')`. [hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) can help you identifying if an element has a specific class. This is a boolean so it will return true if it has the class, otherwise false. You do not need to get the parent and then find the class. You can just select the class if you not the identifier.

Comment: Yes, i tried, but doing how you say is not checking the current element that was clicked, it will check ll elements...